# How to do different operations for samples in a batch in keras?

Tags: split, keras

I have a question about doing different operations for samples in a batch in keras. For example, if the input 'a' is (None, 22, 22, 256) for my custom layer, I wanna do different operations for each sample in this batch, a sample means a[0, :, :, :], a[1, :, :, :]. 
As you know, keras cannot get batch shape (None) unless you have define it at the beginning. So I'm confused how to make this kind layer without knowing batch size, since I have a loop according to batch size.

Comment: Does every sample have a different operations? Then it's not really a batch of samples, they are different inputs to your network.

Comment: I know what you means. However I don't want to train one sample pair once, that's too slow. With pytorch, I can do what I want since I can get batch size.

Comment: Can you add to the question how your code would look like if you did known the batch size? I think it will help to understand what you are trying to accomplish.